# NoSuchMethodError occurring in EsSparkSQL$.saveToES method

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, elasticsearch-spark

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$.saveToEs

The above error occurring when inserting the document from Spark application to the Elasticsearch cluster.

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
     .setAppName("test")
     .setMaster("local[*]") 
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)  val df =.. EsSparkSQL.saveToEs(df,> index, config)
```

Comment: how do you build & run your application?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after changing the elasticsearch-spark version to elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11  from elasticsearch-spark-13_1.6